# how can i fetch a variable outside if?

Tags: java, arrays

Basically this code will run for an interface inside cmd that displays a menu which is menu(); , I cut it for this post. Then it will run options. For the first choice I can insert the amount of students and then insert 3 grades each students. Second choice is doing the average of the sum of those grades, but I cut it for this post. Third choice is for displaying the grades with names based. the problem starts when I try to display and it runs

```
int[][] markah = new int[bilanganpelajar][3];   // 3 row(3 semester), column nama ikut bilnganpelajar
String[] nama = new String[bilanganpelajar];    // using only row to identify markah for each student
```

this in the second loop, these lines reset the array. the output I got is null and 0. the array declaration is also dependent with the studentamount or (bilanganpelajar) and I don't know where should I reposition it.
if my structure is bad I'm sorry, please correct me

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int bilanganpelajar = 0, pilihan = 0, ujian1 = 0, ujian2 = 0, ujian3 = 0;

        do {
            // tunjuk menu
            menu();
            System.out.println("Pilihan anda : ");
            pilihan = input.nextInt();

            if (pilihan == 1) {
                // bilangan pelajar
                insert();
                bilanganpelajar = input.nextInt();              // insert bilangan pelajar
            }
        
            int[][] markah = new int[bilanganpelajar][3];   // 3 row(3 semester), column nama ikut bilnganpelajar
            String[] nama = new String[bilanganpelajar];    // using only row to identify markah for each student

            if (pilihan == 1) {
                // loop
                for(int row = 0; row < bilanganpelajar; row++) {
                    System.out.println("Nama Pelajar : ");
                    nama[row] = input.next();                   // loop ikut 
    
                    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
                        if (column == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Markah Ujian : ");
                            markah[row][column] = input.nextInt();
                            ujian1 += markah[row][0];
                        }
                        else if (column == 1) {
                            System.out.println("Markah Pertengahan Tahun : ");
                            markah[row][column] = input.nextInt();
                            ujian2 += markah[row][1];
                        }
                        else if (column == 2) {
                            System.out.println("Markah Akhir Tahun : ");
                            markah[row][column] = input.nextInt();
                            ujian3 += markah[row][2];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (pilihan == 3) {                 
                //print();
                System.out.println("Nama     Ujian      Pertengahan Tahun      Akhir Tahun");
                for (int row = 0; row < bilanganpelajar; row++) {
                    System.out.println(nama[row]);

                    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
                        System.out.println(markah[row][column]);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            System.out.println("Terima Kasih!");
        }
        while (pilihan != 4);                                   
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Program Tamat");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I kinda cheat for this, I copied

```
// tunjuk menu
            menu();
            System.out.println("Pilihan anda : ");
            pilihan = input.nextInt();

            if (pilihan == 1) {
                // bilangan pelajar
                insert();
                bilanganpelajar = input.nextInt();              // insert bilangan pelajar
            }
        
            int[][] markah = new int[bilanganpelajar][3];   // 3 row(3 semester), column nama ikut bilnganpelajar
            String[] nama = new String[bilanganpelajar];    // using only row to identify markah for each student

            if (pilihan == 1) {
                // loop
                for(int row = 0; row < bilanganpelajar; row++) {
                    System.out.println("Nama Pelajar : ");
                    nama[row] = input.next();                   // loop ikut 
    
                    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
                        if (column == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Markah Ujian : ");
                            markah[row][column] = input.nextInt();
                            ujian1 += markah[row][0];
                        }
                        else if (column == 1) {
                            System.out.println("Markah Pertengahan Tahun : ");
                            markah[row][column] = input.nextInt();
                            ujian2 += markah[row][1];
                        }
                        else if (column == 2) {
                            System.out.println("Markah Akhir Tahun : ");
                            markah[row][column] = input.nextInt();
                            ujian3 += markah[row][2];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

outside of do{} and the declaration inside the do{} which is

```
int[][] markah = new int[bilanganpelajar][3];   // 3 row(3 semester), column nama ikut bilnganpelajar
String[] nama = new String[bilanganpelajar];    // using only row to identify markah for each student
```

i basically erase int[][] and String[]. Thus, I can still make a new array and use the that array

```
markah = new int[bilanganpelajar][3];   // 3 row(3 semester), column nama ikut bilnganpelajar
nama = new String[bilanganpelajar];    // using only row to identify markah for each student
```